# set access permission works in debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, file-permissions, uwp-xaml

I'm developing a UWP software in which i need to write into "input.txt" file located in the Temp directory. however, when giving permission to this directory in release mode i have problem and it seen like the permission is not set:

```
        string str = inputmessage.Text;

        string path = @"input.txt";

        try
        {
            SetAccess(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, 
            Path.GetTempPath());// Path.GetFullPath("."));

            // FileStream.SetAccessControl();
            File.WriteAllText(Path.GetTempPath()+path,str);
        }
```

and set access is defined as:

```
       private static bool SetAccess(string user, string folder)
    {
        const FileSystemRights Rights = FileSystemRights.FullControl;

        // *** Add Access Rule to the actual directory itself
        var AccessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(user, Rights,
            InheritanceFlags.None,
            PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit,
            AccessControlType.Allow);

        var Info = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
        var Security = Info.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
        bool Result;

        Security.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Set, AccessRule, out Result);

        if (!Result) return false;

        // *** Always allow objects to inherit on a directory
        const InheritanceFlags iFlags = InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit;

        // *** Add Access rule for the inheritance
        AccessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(user, Rights,
            iFlags,
            PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
            AccessControlType.Allow);

        Security.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Add, AccessRule, out Result);

        if (!Result) return false;

        Info.SetAccessControl(Security);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: have you checked app.manifest for permissions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FileSystemAccessRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule?view=netframework-4.7.2) is belong to [`System.Security.AccessControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) Namespace, and it is not [compatible](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/wiki/UWP-Compat#acl) with uwp. You could not use it to access [TemporaryFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.temporaryfolder#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_TemporaryFolder).

If you want to write into "input.txt" file located in the Temp directory. Please refer the following process.

```
private async void writeTextToTem(string info)
{
    var file = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("info.text", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    if (file != null)
    {
        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, info);
    }
}
```

And [`Path.GetTempPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppatha) also work in uwp, and the matching folder is 
`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Packages\497f6a93-9de3-4985-b27e-c2215ebabe72_75crXXXXXXX\AC\Temp\`, it is contained in the app's sandbox you could access it directly.

```
var path = Path.GetTempPath();
var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("info.text", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
if (file != null)
{
    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, str);
}
```

For more detail you could refer [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Comment: first code doesn't work in release mode. and in  the second code you haven't written any string into the file?

Comment: I have written `path` string to the file.

Comment: thanks your second code works perfectly but it should be amended to Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file,str);